# Java Util Timer Start

Tags: java, timer

I've created a Java Timer for a lock function in a flex project. I've been reading up and I know there are two different types of Timers (util and swing). The question I have is, how does the util timer start? I have looked and there is no explicit method for starting the timer like the swing timer.

Answer (score 0):

The `schedule` methods already provide mechanisms on when to start. For example, from the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date%29):

```
public void schedule(TimerTask task, Date time)
```

> Schedules the specified task for execution at the specified time. If
>   the time is in the past, the task is scheduled for immediate
>   execution.

This timer will start on the specified time.

Comment: I see, thanks. I was following an example which didnt have a method liek this. I will have a look into this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use schedule method to specify when to start.

```
void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)
```

Here delay could be 0 to start now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either the `schedule` or `scheduleAtFixedInterval` methods to start a `TimerTask`, which the `Timer` class controls as below. Calling either of the methods starts the timer automatically unless a delay is specified.

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }   
};

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, new Date(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)); // Starts automatically
```

Comment: I have a schedlueAtFixedrate in my timer class, will that still run? Or will I have to call it from a method in another class?

Comment: Yes, it will run provided it is called as in my example above, regardless of where it is called from (either internally from a class extending `Timer` or externally in another class). If it doesn't run, check the delay period and the next scheduled time parameters.